# Curl is slow (I assume I am not setting an option correctly)

Tags: c++, curl

I have written this minimal example that shows my problem:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    // All error checking removed for clarity.
    // But all calls return CURLE_OK

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20120405 Firefox/14.0a1");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1]);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    long    result;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &result);

    std::cout << "HTTP RESPONCE: " << result << "\n";
}
```

Compile and run:

```
> g++ test.cpp -lcurl
> ./a.out thorsanvil.com
<html><head><title>Nothing here</title></head><body><h1>Nothing Here</h1><h2>Go away</h2></body></html>
HTTP RESPONCE: 200

real    0m5.144s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.000s
```

As you can see it is taking 5 seconds to get a response from the server.
If I repeat the same command using wget it takes only 0.2 -> 0.5 seconds

```
> time wget thorsanvil.com
--2012-05-28 05:24:17--  http://thorsanvil.com/
Resolving thorsanvil.com (thorsanvil.com)... 67.170.22.105
Connecting to thorsanvil.com (thorsanvil.com)|67.170.22.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

    100%[======================================================================================================================>] 104         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-05-28 05:24:18 (589 KB/s) - `index.html.3' saved [104/104]


real    0m0.493s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.000s
```

But using the curl command line tools is also slow

```
> time curl thorsanvil.com
<html><head><title>Nothing here</title></head><body><h1>Nothing Here</h1><h2>Go away</h2></body></html>

real    0m5.240s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Any ideas on why my simple version is not working as expected?

#### Edited

From comments. Version of libcurl

```
> ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 748262 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 360488 Mar 22 16:52 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    950 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Mar 22 16:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 381512 Mar 22 16:52 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0

> curl --version
curl 7.21.7 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with optimizations? `-O3`?

Comment: strange indeed. I get comparable timings when running your code vs wget.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Same result with (-g (debug)) and (-O3 (release))

Comment: Maybe you can try to `strace` it and post the output.

Comment: Knowing what libcurl version you are using might be helpful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Not sure what happened to the system.

So I go the admin to un-install then re-install curl.

Everything is now working correctly.
So it looks like the curl version got messed up somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea what version it was before and after? Perhaps a bug that's been fixed?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I don't know the original curl version. But they had the same version number on the shared libs "4.2.0". This machine was built from scratch (by a new ops (from colledge)). Apparently there was a custom build (I found out this morning) of curl that was configured to use `libares`. I have no idea what the problem was as yet. If I get more information I will post details. But the plain vanilla curl retrieved via apt-get works fine.